# Notation in Siu's paper

Tags: notation, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, several-complex-variables

In the following paper of Siu Yum-Tong:https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1967-018-05/S0002-9939-1967-0216032-3/S0002-9939-1967-0216032-3.pdf, which he proved that Cartan B implies A, he used the notation $\mathfrak{J}\mathfrak{F}$, where the first is a sheaf of germs of holomorphic functions vanishing at some point $x\in X$, where $X$ is Stein, and $\mathfrak{F}$ is a coherent analytic sheaf on $X$. What could he possibly mean by this notation. It doesn't seem standard as I have never seen this before.

Comment: Is it not just the tensor product, so that away from $x$ the stalk is just the stalk of $\mathscr F$, and any open containing $x$ we get sections of $\mathscr F$ vanishing at $x$?

Comment: @TedShifrin That's what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure if the tensor product is contained in $\mathfrak{F}$ as we need it for the exact sequence.

Comment: The ideal sheaf is a subsheaf of the structure sheaf, no?

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh yeah, you are right. I forgot about that. Thanks.

Comment: You might as well write an answer to your question. :)